# iOS/Android store and buy credits from outside respective stores (No in app purchases)

Tags: android, ios, web, app-store

I am in the middle of developing a game, which is targeted for Android, iOS, Web.

User's has to create an account to play the game, and he can use that account in any of the 3 above mentioned platform.

As user plays more, he can unlock/purchase new features (weapons) and I need to store the details of these purchases in a centralized database server. I am thinking of implementing this like

- When user click `unlock` during game (in any of iPhone, Android or
  Web), a new web page is shown, where user can buy the feature using
  paypal or any other methods.
- In mobile devices when user clicks unlock mobile version of this web
  page is shown in a web view
- When user buys/unlocks a feature, the data is stored in centralized
  database.
- In short I don't want to use in app purchase on respective mobile devices.

My questions are these

1. Anything in iTunes store/google play rules forbidding this kind of
   purchase/business? Will Apple/google objects to these?
2. If Apple/Google does objects, then my only option is to use **in
   app purchase**. In that case, how can I implement a centralized
   feature unlock/purchase system which works across all platform? **I
   don't want my user to be annoyed because the weapon he bought in
   iPhone is not there when he plays in Web.**

Comment: You can be certain that Apple will not allow it.

The In-App purchase is just a way for you to get your money, run the same code as you would when getting money from paypal and mark the item as purchased.

Comment: Well, then say UserA purchased a weapon in Android (in app purchase there) by paying 1$. So user already payed for the item. When he opens then on iOS, that weapon should be already available to him. Since this weapon is already listed as buyable in iOS app store, I need to (programmatically)purchase it again, to mark it as purchased, right?

Comment: You are the one who decides what is purchasable in your app, so if it is marked as purchased in the central database, it just should not be for sale anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Anything in iTunes store/google play rules forbidding this kind of purchase/business? Will Apple/google objects to these?

With iOS, you can't do this:

> a new web page is shown, where user can buy the feature using paypal
> or any other method

Any purchase *visble inside the app* has to use IAP. So you could make purchases on other platforms available in the iOS version pretty easily.

As for making purchases. Either you use IAP or you allow the option on your website. But *don't* provide a link inside your app to the "Buy now" option on your website.

Have a look at the Kindle app to see how you have to do it.

- If Apple/Google does objects, then my only option is to use in app purchase. In that case, how can I implement a centralized feature unlock/purchase system which works across all platform? I don't want my user to be annoyed because the weapon he bought in iPhone is not there when he plays in Web.

With iOS, only the billing has to go through their servers. You can trigger downloads/events on your own server, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, just to make it certain 1) When purchase using iOS IAP, notify server that this item is purchased, so it is visible in Android/Web 2) When purchased using Android/Web, sync with server on what items are purchased (when opening in iPhone), and unlock them in your game (no IAP purchase, and the item remains unpurchased in itunes connect). 3) Do exactly same in Android also. Am I right in everything?